# Wrong activity on home button and start renew

Tags: android

i have an android application that have 2 activities, A and B.
Then, when i start the activity A, go to the activity B (button), press home and clicking the app in launcher i open it and hope the activity B, but its the activity A.

Why?

In manifest for activity A i have this

```
<activity android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

In activity B launchMode:singleTask and this in the intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If we do not add launch mode for activities in manifest file,the default implementation is as below:

1.Activity A --> Activity B
2.Pressed Home button. 
3.launch application again from launcher

Result:
Activity B will be seen. (If application is not killed).

Which behavior you are expecting.
```

2. If you declare ActivityA and B as below in manifest file:

   ```
           <activity android:name=".ActivityA"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTask" 
            >

           <activity android:name=".ActivityA"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTask" 
            >
   ```

   Steps:
       1.Activity A --> Activity B
       2.Pressed Home button. 
       3.launch application again from launcher

   Result: Activity A will be seen.

   Reason:

   If we add android:launchMode="singleTask" for activity, activity will be created in new task. If you launch application again, existing activity backstack will be removed and activity will be created in new task again.
   That is why you are  not able to see Activity B when you launch app again.

   If some more clarification required, add your comments.

Comment: Sorry i have activity a declared for launch mode..how can i set activity a for launch mode and get my desired workflow?                Activitya->activityb->home->activityb

Comment: @colymore can you check with below launch modes:<activity android:name=".ActivityA"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:launchMode="standard" 
         >

        <activity android:name=".ActivityB"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:launchMode="standard" 
         >             you will get the expected behavior. Activitya->activityb->home->activityb

Answer (score 0):

Try 
android:launchMode="singleInstance" in manifest